# How does Caffeine work?

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, hibernate

[Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) should prevent Ubuntu from falling into *hibernation* or *suspend mode*. It's not working for me so far, maybe I do some mistake:

I have opened `Caffeine Indicator`, activated it (cup has rising steam) and computer fall into hibernation after 30 minutes while terminal has active command or Firefox has active download. Some tech. details:

- `Lubuntu 14.04`
- Caffeine has version `2.8.3`
- `caffeine` process runs on background

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, you understand that my problem is not `Caffeine` behaviour but **system falling into hibernation while doing some job**. But, you know, now the lazy consumer speaks from me: I don't want to code in order to solve this "stupid-simple-basic" problem. This is what Canonical (developers) should do! I just want to click with mouse like "simple" Win user without using my brain :-)

Comment: First of all, I will try to find out if I use Caffeine properly, then I will search for another solutions... Caffeine (Kofeín) doesn't develop Canonical, but Ubuntu _falling into hibernation while doing a job_ does :-) I'm ex Win user who just fall in love with Ubuntu. It's not easy relationship but no Windows any more :-)

Comment: @DKBose, there is only link to [article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine) about Caffeine I have already read: _Caffeine is now fully automatic: when the active window is full screen, Caffeine inhibits desktop idleness (and thereby disables the screen saver and/or screen sleep)..._ What is considered to be a "fullscreen" activity? When I surf Firefox in `maximized` window or when I surf in Firefox through `F11`? In both cases machine fall into hibernation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Keep.Awake instead of Caffeine https://launchpad.net/keep.awake

I haven't developed a GUI for it yet so you will need to use the command prompt.

I still haven't gotten around to creating a snap or deb for it. However temporarily you can download the program from Launchpad [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ferncasado/keep.awake/trunk/files/head:/v4/)

The current version is stable and works on all Ubuntu versions from 14.04 up to 16.04. That said I am continually improving it and will be adding new features.

It works like a proper command. Type --help to see a full listing of what can be done. The examples underneath are only a few:

```
./keepawake.py --help
```

To run interactively:

```
./keepawake.py
```

To run as a background service:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set 15 min (900 sec) as the user activity idle time before it determines that the user is idle:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -u 900 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set minimum CPU load as 13%:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -c 13 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set minimum network traffic as 5KB (5120 bytes):

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -s 5120 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run all three settings above (network, CPU, User idle) in the one go:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -s 5120 -c 13 -u 900 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```